# How to build a Twitter Bot that tweets 'pre-defined' texts, image(optional), url

Tags: python, twitter, bots, tweepy

I'd like to build in Python a Twitter Bot that automatically posts product info(product image(optional), product name, short description, shortened url) that are defined in csv or something at a certain interval.

I've only been researching how to do this however have had no luck finding out how.

I'd appreciate receiving a link to a site for good reference or any direction to achieve this if possible at all. thanx!

Comment: Hi Yuji, it would be helpful if you shared how far you have got? Any code you have attempted, resources you have already tried?

Comment: Hi Adam, Regret to say but so far I've only been looking for resources that help me put this all together and not got around to coding it yet.. I'm not an experienced coder but I think I could code to create a bot that auto tweets simple text but I have no idea if it's even possible to do what I've explained in my question... i will do more research on my end. thanx!